# @RenderSection at Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I try to use the @RenderSection in my website which built with Razor script. I got error when use it with the .cshtml files. It also didn't appear in the IntelliSense at VS.

Now, I just realized that if I remove the @page from the .cshtml file then the error gone and also the IntelliSense offer me the @RenderSection

And my question is: why?

It says in the Microsoft documentation / tutorial that with the new ASP.NET Core Razor scripts:

"@page must be the first Razor directive on a page. @page affects the behavior of other Razor constructs."

So I'm a little bit confused. What's the right way to include html (partial views - like main menu, etc.) in a .cshtml file with the new Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core ?

Thanks.

Comment: what error you are getting without `@page` ? Is it compile time error or run time error?

Comment: The error is with '@page'. Without page there isn't an error. The error I get with '@page' is "The name 'RenderSection' does not exist in the current context". But since in Microsoft's tutorial it says to use '@page', then I want to know what's the right way to include html blocks while using '@page'.

Comment: Are you using `@RenderSection` on layout page?

Comment: No. On _Layout.cshtml there isn't a problem. The problem is with other .cshtml pages. The thing is, the structure of the internal pages is slightly different then the homepage, so I have different headers. What I try to do is to have a partial view for the menu (and for other code blocks that repeat themselves) and then to call them. In the 'old' Razor pages you could just put them in the shared folder and using them with the RenderSection. Now with the new one, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have work around on this and found when you use `@RenderSection` in child page than it should be inside any section of its parent page(i.e. _layout.cshtml)

Here your `_layout.cshtml` should be like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  </head>
<body>
  @RenderSection("MenuContent", false) 
  @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Your child page should like,

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section MenuContent {
  @RenderSection("MenuContent", false)
}
```

And your nested child page should like,

```
@section MenuContent
{
    <!-- content -->
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Kind of little complicated. Or, I'll just create two layouts - one for homepage and one for the internal pages. I tried to do what angular offers when having components and then just have let's say the menu as a component and can call it from any other component. Was wandering if there's an easy way to do it with Razor