# Placement of style tag in view

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Looking at some Razor views, I see a lot of times where a `<style>` tag is added directly in a view (CSHTML) file.

This seems to work fine, but in fact it adds the `<style>` tag inside the `<body>` tag, while it should generally be inside the `<head>` tag.

How would you some inline CSS to a single razor page so that it appears within the `<head>` tag? Is there a preferred way?

Comment: Do you want to add CSS or script? Both are mentioned.

Comment: @ScottHannen: Sorry. I fixed the question. I want to add CSS styles.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736189/rendersection-at-razor-pages). The question implies that you're using a layout view. This lets your layout view define a section within its head element, and then your view declares the @section element and adds stuff to the layout.

Comment: Haven't done razor view in awhile but I believe they have `@RenderSection` that you can put in side your `head` tag and on view's you would do `@section name`

Comment: @penleychan: What do you use now instead of razor?

Comment: My current position we mainly we do React and Angular with webapi, slowly moving to dotnet core.

Comment: @penleychan: Oh, I was under the impression Angular worked with Razor. I'm clearly behind on that front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

`Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("HeadStyles", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

`Home/Index.cshtml` or whatever other view you need to do this in

```
@section HeadStyles {
    <style>
        .custom-style { color: red; }
    </style>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why inclusion of `<style>` tags is not recommended inside `<body>` is because of causing [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

But if your `<style>` tag applies to content that's ***after*** it in DOM, that risk is `null`.

No browser currently in use has any trouble parsing `<style>` tags placed in `<body>`.
Technically, when the browser meets a `<style>` tag in DOM it:

- pauses rendering
- reconstructs CSSOM to include the new declarations
- rebuilds the already rendered DOM (this is where FOUC happens, if)
- carries on with rendering

Answer (score -1):

best variant is -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">       
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- here is page content -->             
        <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

in this case browser will load in this sequence

1. styles
2. content (which will be already styled)
3. scripts (which will not slow down page rendering in case if scipts are not so little)